How to install Windows update KB5044285? Having issues
Today I got the update KB5044285 and Windows restarted then it gave me the message that something is wrong and rolling back the update.
I booted into safe mode and disabled Malwarebytes but still installing the update fail.
How do I install this update?


You’re going to need to provide your Windows Update logs to diagnose this issue. 0x800f0922 typically has nothing to do with AVs especially since multiple updates are blocked. This seems extremely familiar

Yes I tried this method about App Readiness service. What are the logs name ? CBS ?

I found the solution. I disabled Secure Boot from the Bios and update installed successfully

You’ll want to immediately enable Secure Boot.

@jdf - The you don’t have the same problem
